# UserMailer with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionmailer, mailer

am using my custom mailer UserMailer to send emails. It works perfect in development, but in production i get error 500, that is when am trying to retrieve my password on forgetting.

here is what is in the production logs in the production mode

```
  Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "user"=>{"email"=>"sam@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Send me r$
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

 NameError (uninitialized constant Devise::UserMailer):
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in  constantize'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `constantize'
devise (2.1.2) lib/devise.rb:256:in `get'
devise (2.1.2) lib/devise.rb:279:in `mailer'
```

my mailer configuration. user_mailer.rb

```
 class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer 

  default :from => "info@xxxxxxxx.com"  

 def signup_confirmation(user)
   @user = user
   mail :to => user.email, :subject=> "Thank you for signing with us"
end

# send password reset instructions

def reset_password_instructions(user)
  @resource = user
  mail(:to => @resource.email, :subject => "Reset password instructions", :tag => 'password-reset', :content_type => "text/html") do |format|
   format.html { render "devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions" }
  end
end  
end
```

production.rb file

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com'  }

config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

 config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true


   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'info@xxxxxxxx.com',
      :user_name            => 'yyyyyy',
      :password             => 'zzzzzzzz',
      :authentication       => 'plain',
      :openssl_verify_mode => 'none',
     :enable_starttls_auto => true  

    }
```

your assistance will be highly appreciated

Comment: could you post your mailer config please

Comment: I have posted. thanks for your willingness to help me

Comment: Just out of interest have you set up the smtp settings in your `production.rb`? If so post this!

Comment: Further to this why are you including the `def reset_password_instructions(user)` in the mailer. Devise sets all of this automatically for you ;/

Comment: i have smtp settings in my production.rb already

Comment: without **def reset_password_instructions(user)** i only get blank msg on reseting password in development. with this, my reset password works, but only in development. with it, or without it, production development fails with error 500 i have shown  name:@David

Comment: @PetersonSamsam have you got the devise controllers in your application?

Comment: @PetersonSamsam See my detailed answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay from the looks of it your mailer looks wrong. Especially the set up. By default you can create a mailer like this:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => DEFAULT_FROM
  def registration_confirmation(user)
    @user = user
    @url = "http://localhost:3000/login"
    mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "Registered")

  end
end
```

What I did notice in your example is that your doing:

```
 class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer
```

Your inheriting from Devise's Mailer when in actual fact you shouldn't have do any of this! You may also want to check your `config/initalizers/devise.rb and set the`config.mailer_sender=example@gmail.com`  if you haven't. So what I suggest you doing is make your mailer look like the following:

```
 class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base 

  default :from => "info@xxxxxxxx.com"  

 def signup_confirmation(user)
   @user = user
   mail :to => user.email, :subject=> "Thank you for signing with us"
end
```

Also another thing... I noticed that your default url is: `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'https://xxxxxxxxxx.com'  }` there is no need for `https` so it should really look like `config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'xxxxxxxxxx.com'  }`. Because when you try to fire anything what will happen is that it will be doing `https://https://https://xxxxxxxxxx.com`. This is an easy mistake for people to make.

And I also believe the cause of this may be due to the fact you have not set the class that is responsible for sending your e-mails.

**Other possible solution that may fix your problem**

Notice that in `config/intializers/devise.rb` that there is the following line which is commented out:

```
  # Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  # config.mailer = "Devise::Mailer"
```

Uncomment this and set this to your class you are using which in your example so that it would be

```
 config.mailer = "UserMailer" # UserMailer is your mailer class
```

Also in app/mailers/user_mailer.rb you should have:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

  default from: "default@mydomain.com"

  def confirmation_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions)
  end

  def reset_password_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions)
  end

  def unlock_instructions(record)
    devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions)
  end

  # you can then put any of your own methods here
end
```

May also want to generate your own views:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

also move the email templates from app/views/devise/mailer/ to app/views/user_mailer/

> mv app/views/devise/mailer/* app/views/user_mailer/

Comment: Thanks, it seems i was mixed up. i applied your recomendations, and now everything works fine

Comment: In the devise instructions, it says to inherit your mailer from devise though? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer

Answer (score 2):

Do everthing @david has said. except change this for the Devise > 3.2.4

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @token = token
  devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
end

def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @token = token
  devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
end

def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  @token = token
  devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts)
end
```

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much!!